# Drawing a cuboid with rounded corners

Tags: graphics3d

I want to draw a cuboid with rounded corners, like this:

[image: key]

`RoundingRadius` only works with `Rectangle` or `Framed`. I have no idea how to draw a cuboid with rounded corners. What are your ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I think should be possible to do this using `BSplineSurface` and it would be the "ultimate" way, creating a precise, single-piece shape, but frankly I'm too lazy to figure it out as it's far from trivial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two more options. These allow direct control of the box dimensions and the rounding radius.

---

Using `ContourPlot3D`:

```
signedDistance[p_, p0_, p1_] := Piecewise[
  {{-Min[p - p0, p1 - p], And @@ Thread[p0 <= p <= p1]}, 
   {EuclideanDistance[p, MapThread[Min[Max[#1, #2], #3] &, {p, p0, p1}]], True}}]
roundedCuboidPlot[p0 : {x0_, y0_, z0_}, p1 : {x1_, y1_, z1_}, r_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ContourPlot3D[signedDistance[{x, y, z}, p0 + r, p1 - r] == r, 
  {x, x0 - r, x1 + r}, {y, y0 - r, y1 + r}, {z, z0 - r, z1 + r}, opts]

roundedCuboidPlot[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, 1/4, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

---

Using `Graphics3D` primitives:

```
roundedCuboid[p0 : {x0_, y0_, z0_}, p1 : {x1_, y1_, z1_}, r_] := 
 {EdgeForm[None], 
  Cuboid[p0 + {0, r, r}, p1 - {0, r, r}], 
  Cuboid[p0 + {r, 0, r}, p1 - {r, 0, r}], 
  Cuboid[p0 + {r, r, 0}, p1 - {r, r, 0}], 
  Table[Cylinder[{{x0 + r, y, z}, {x1 - r, y, z}}, r], 
   {y, {y0 + r, y1 - r}}, {z, {z0 + r, z1 - r}}], 
  Table[Cylinder[{{x, y0 + r, z}, {x, y1 - r, z}}, r], 
   {x, {x0 + r, x1 - r}}, {z, {z0 + r, z1 - r}}], 
  Table[Cylinder[{{x, y, z0 + r}, {x, y, z1 - r}}, r], 
   {x, {x0 + r, x1 - r}}, {y, {y0 + r, y1 - r}}], 
  Table[Sphere[{x, y, z}, r], 
   {x, {x0 + r, x1 - r}}, {y, {y0 + r, y1 - r}}, {z, {z0 + r, z1 - r}}]}

Graphics3D[{roundedCuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, 1/4]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The second way is great!Since I need to add one texture on cuboid, i just replace a Cuboid to Polygon，then I can use  Texture.Thx.

Comment: Nice, I was to lazyto write this ;) p.s. you can skip `Spheres` and replace `Cylinders` with `Tubes`.

Answer (score 17):

```
ClearAll[roundedCuboidF]
roundedCuboidF[hprof_: 10, vprof_: 10, taper_: 1][box_] := 
    ChartElementDataFunction["DoubleProfileCube", "HorizontalProfile" -> hprof, 
                            "VerticalProfile" -> vprof, "TaperRatio" -> taper][box]

Graphics3D[roundedCuboidF[][{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

or

```
ContourPlot3D[Norm[{x, y, z}, 4], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
  Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral",
  ContourStyle ->  Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

[image]

Comment: not for keypad use: `roundedCuboidF[1, 1, 0.01]`. Nice thing to play with and very instructive :)

Comment: Thx!But I can not find ChartElementDataFunction in Reference Centre, so How should I learn this function？

Comment: @Chenminqi, try [ChartElementFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) and examples there and `Chart Element Schemes` in the `Palettes` menu.

Comment: @eldo, thank you!  -- looks nicer with `Directive[Red, Specularity[White, 30]]` and `Lighting->"Neutral" :)

Answer (score 9):

Rahul's otherwise fine approach has a drawback that can be seen if you include an `Opacity[]` directive:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[2/3, Pink], roundedCuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, 1/4]},
           Boxed -> False]
```

[image: look at 'em ribs!]

The "ribs" may or may not be desirable in an application, so I sought an alternative that does not use too many `Polygon[]`s (as with the solutions based on plotting) and yet looks fine when made translucent.

The following routine is not quite Mr. Wizard's wish in the comments, but it is certainly built from `BSplineSurface[]` + `Polygon[]` components:

```
roundedCuboid[p1_?VectorQ, p2_?VectorQ, r_?NumericQ] := 
       Module[{csk, csw, cv, ei, fi, ocp, osk, owt},
              cv = Tuples[Transpose[{p1 + r, p2 - r}]];
              ocp = {{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}},
                     {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}},
                     {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}};
              osk = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}};
              owt = {{1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/2, 1/Sqrt[2]},
                     {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}};
              ei = {{{4, 8}, {2, 6}, {1, 5}, {3, 7}},
                    {{6, 8}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}, {5, 7}},
                    {{7, 8}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}, {5, 6}}};
              csk = {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}};
              csw = {{1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}, {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}};
              fi = {{8, 6, 5, 7}, {8, 7, 3, 4}, {8, 4, 2, 6},
                    {4, 3, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 7, 5}};
              Flatten[{EdgeForm[], BSplineSurface3DBoxOptions ->
                                   {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 35}}, 
                       MapIndexed[BSplineSurface[Map[
                       AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[π Mod[#2[[1]] - 1, 4]/2,
                                        {0, 0, 1}], #1}], 
                       ocp.DiagonalMatrix[r {1, 1, If[Mod[#2[[1]] - 1, 8] < 4,
                                                      1, -1]}], {2}], 
                       SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> osk, SplineWeights -> owt] &,
                       cv[[{8, 4, 2, 6, 7, 3, 1, 5}]]], 
                       MapIndexed[Function[{idx, pos}, 
                          BSplineSurface[Outer[Plus, cv[[idx]], 
                          Composition[Insert[#, 0, pos[[1]]] &, 
                                      RotationTransform[π (pos[[2]] - 1)/2]] /@
                          (r {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}), 1], SplineDegree -> {1, 2},
                          SplineKnots -> csk, SplineWeights -> csw]], ei, {2}], 
                       Polygon[MapThread[Map[TranslationTransform[r #2], cv[[#1]]] &,
                               {fi, Join[#, -#] &[IdentityMatrix[3]]}]]}]]
```

Using this version instead in the first snippet yields the following picture:

[image: no ribs, ma!]

Some more examples:

```
Graphics3D[{Yellow, roundedCuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, 1/10],
            Blue, roundedCuboid[{2, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 3}, 1/4]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: still life of two rounded cuboids]

```
Graphics3D[{{EdgeForm[Gray], Opacity[1/2, Green], Cuboid[{2, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 3}]},
            {Pink, roundedCuboid[{2, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 3}, 1/5]}},
           Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: peek-a-boo]

Comment: B-spline surface was my first thought, too, but it would take me too long to figure out how to do it.  Nice job.  +1

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I already knew how to build NURBS representations of sphere octants and cylinder quarters; organizing them to form the corner filleting was what took the most work from me.

Answer (score 6):

```
f = PolyhedronData["Cube", "RegionFunction"][x, y, z];

r = 2; u = 0.6;

RegionPlot3D[f, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r}, Mesh -> False, 
 PlotPoints -> 55, PlotRange -> {{-u, u}, {-u, u}, {-u, u}}]
```

[image]

Weakness of this approach: You have to find the right number for `PlotPoints` (here 55) by trial and error.

Comment: `f` is a cube with straight edges covering `{{-0.5,0.5},{-0.5,0.5},{-0.5,0.5}}`. This volume is completely inside `{{-2,2},...}` and `{{-0.6,0.6},...}` so how does this even work? Is it a side effect of `RegionPlot3D` not having high enough resolution?

Comment: @C.E. Yes, it is (see last sentence of my answer).

Answer (score 6):

This approach takes advantage of a [weakness](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108005/9490) in the implementation of `DiscretizeRegion` wherein I give it a perfectly cubic region, and it returns a poor approximation of it,

```
MeshRegion[
 DiscretizeRegion@
  ImplicitRegion[{0, 0, 0} <= {x, y, z} <= {1, 1, 1}, {x, y, z}],
 PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading"]
```

[image]

This has less smoothness on the corners like the other answers, but I think it matches the image in the OP pretty well.

Comment: We can take it a step further and apply `LoopSubdivide` (defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161332/4346)). `Nest[LoopSubdivide, BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[{0, 0, 0} <= {x, y, z} <= {1, 1, 1}, {x, y, z}], Method -> "MarchingCubes"], 2]` https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttUaQ.png

Answer (score 3):

A new command `RegionDilation` (since 2021) does the job:

```
RegionDilation[Region[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}]],  Region[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1/2]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the ResourceFunction [RoundedCuboid](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RoundedCuboid/) (added January 2022)

```
rcube = ResourceFunction["RoundedCuboid"];

Graphics3D[{MaterialShading["Pewter"], rcube[]},
 Boxed -> False,
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{
  MaterialShading["Brass"],
  rcube[{0, 0, 0}, {6, 3, 3}, RoundingRadius -> {0.5, 0, 0.5}]},
 Boxed -> False,
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
solid = Cuboid[];
solid = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Polyhedron"];
n = MeshCellCount[solid, 1];
bmesh[solid_, k_] := 
  Module[{shape, fillet, bm}, shape = OpenCascadeShape[solid];
   fillet = OpenCascadeShapeFillet[shape, .15, Take[Range[2 n], k]];
   bm = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[fillet, 
     "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> .1}];
   groups = bm["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
   colors = ColorData["BrightBands"] /@ Subdivide[Length@groups];
   bm["Wireframe"[
     "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[#]] & /@ 
        colors)]]];
ani = Table[
   Show[bmesh[solid, k], PlotRange -> RegionBounds[solid]], {k, 1, 
    2 n}];
Export["test.gif", ani, "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞, 
  "DisplayDurations" -> .2, "ControlAppearance" -> None] // SystemOpen
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot3D[
  Norm[{x, y, z}, norm] <= 1
  , {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}
  , Mesh -> Ceiling /@ {norm, norm, norm}
  ]
 , {{norm, 2}, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]