# Poor performance from Graphics3D

Tags: performance-tuning, graphics3d, game

I wrote a game -- 2048，Some codes are from [http://blog.wolfram.com/](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/05/09/2048/). My codes are in [notebook downloads](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbaayh7kluskkig/2048%20game%EF%BC%882D%20and%203D%29.nb)

I added code so that the game can play in 3D form, but when I play it, I find that it is too slow, so I write some test code to investigate performance.

[image]

The front end seems to be too slow to update the complex 3D graphics in real time. How can I deal with this?

### Edit 1:  The main relevant codes

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SetOptions[Graphics3D, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
$empty = "";

colors = {"Color" -> #1, "Background" -> #2} & @@@ {{"#776e65", 
 "#eee4da"}, {"#776e65", "#ede0c8"}, {"#f9f6f2", 
 "#f2b179"}, {"#f9f6f2", "#f59563"}, {"#f9f6f2", 
 "#f67c5f"}, {"#f9f6f2", "#f65e3b"}, {"#f9f6f2", 
 "#edcf72"}, {"#f9f6f2", "#edcc61"}, {"#f9f6f2", 
 "#edc850"}, {"#f9f6f2", "#edc53f"}, {"#f9f6f2", "#edc22e"}};
hexToRGB[s_String] := 
  RGBColor @@ (IntegerDigits[FromDigits[StringTake[s, -6], 16], 256, 3]/255.);
colorForNumber[n_Integer, s_] := hexToRGB[s /. colors[[Log[2, n]]]];
$emptyColor = RGBColor[0.75436, 0.701427, 0.642634];
$backgroundColor = RGBColor[0.676677, 0.616403, 0.559747];

(*draw 3D*)
drawTile[n_Integer, pos_: {0, 0}] := 
 Module[{texture, x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, r},
   {{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}} = pos - # & /@ {0.45, -0.45};
   z0 = -.1; z1 = Log[2, n]/11; r = 1/16;
   texture = 
   Graphics[{colorForNumber[n, "Background"], 
     Polygon[{{-0.45, -0.45}, {-0.45, 0.45}, {0.45, 0.45}, {0.45, -0.45}}], 
     Text[Style[n, Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
     FontSize -> Scaled@Switch[IntegerLength@n, 1 | 2, .5, 3, .4, _, .34], 
     colorForNumber[n, "Color"]]]}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRange -> 0.4];
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm@None, 
     colorForNumber[n, "Background"], {Texture@texture, 
     Polygon[{{x0 + r, y0 + r, z1}, {x1 - r, y0 + r, z1},
       {x1 - r, y1 - r, z1}, {x0 + r, y1 - r, z1}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]},
  Cuboid[{x0, y0, z0} + #, {x1, y1, z1} - #] & /@ {{0, r, r}, {r, 0, r}},
  Table[Tube[{{x0 + r, y, z}, {x1 - r, y, z}}, r], 
      {y, {y0 + r, y1 - r}}, {z, {z0 + r, z1 - r}}], 
  Table[Tube[{{x, y0 + r, z}, {x, y1 - r, z}}, r],
      {x, {x0 + r, x1 - r}}, {z, {z0 + r, z1 - r}}], 
  Table[Tube[{{x, y, z0 + r}, {x, y, z1 - r}}, r], 
       {x, {x0 + r, x1 - r}}, {y, {y0 + r, y1 - r}}]}]
 ];
drawTile[$empty, pos_: {0, 0}] := 
  Module[{texture, x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, r},
   {{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}} = pos - # & /@ {0.45, -0.45}; 
  z0 = -.1; z1 = 1/22; r = 1/16;
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm@None, $emptyColor, {Polygon[{{x0 + r, y0 + r, z1},
     {x1 - r, y0 + r, z1}, {x1 - r, y1 - r, z1}, {x0 + r, y1 - r, z1}}]},
    Cuboid[{x0, y0, z0} + #, {x1, y1, z1} - #] & /@ {{0, r, r}, {r, 0, r}},
    Table[Tube[{{x0 + r, y, z}, {x1 - r, y, z}}, r],
       {y, {y0 + r, y1 - r}}, {z, {z0 + r, z1 - r}}], 
    Table[Tube[{{x, y0 + r, z}, {x, y1 - r, z}}, r],
       {x, {x0 + r, x1 - r}}, {z, {z0 + r, z1 - r}}], 
    Table[Tube[{{x, y, z0 + r}, {x, y, z1 - r}}, r], 
       {x, {x0 + r, x1 - r}}, {y, {y0 + r, y1 - r}}]}]];
drawBottom = Graphics3D[{$backgroundColor, 
    Cuboid[{0.4, 0.4, -0.1}, {4.6, 4.6, 0}]}];
drawGrid[board_] := Show[drawBottom, 
   Table[drawTile[board[[i, j]], {i, j}], {i, 4}, {j, 4}], 
   PlotRange -> {{0.5, 4.5}, {0.5, 4.5}, {-0.05, 1}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   ViewPoint -> {2.13, -0.69, 2.53}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];
```

I want to write the game -- 2048 in 3D form ,like this:

[image]

So First I need to plot the cuboid with rounded corners and texture.So I used
Polygon,Text,Texture to realize the texture，and use Polygon,Cuboid,Cuboid to realize the cuboid with rounded corners.This is the function drawTile[].Then I just need to draw 16 
cubes with function drawGrid[].And then the trouble is coming.The drawGrid contains a large number of primitives.It is quickly calculate in kernel.But if show it in the front end ，it will cost a long time that can not negligible.Here is the test codes.

```
data = Partition[RandomSample@PadLeft[2^# & /@ Range[11], 16, $empty],4];
m = AbsoluteTime[];
Show[drawGrid[data], ImageSize -> 150] // AbsoluteTiming
AbsoluteTime[] - m
m = AbsoluteTime[];
Show[drawGrid[data], ImageSize -> 150]; // AbsoluteTiming
AbsoluteTime[] - m
```

[image]

Actually when I press the arrow key ,it will be 0.5s delay before image update in 3D form  games, while it will be less than 0.1s delay in 2D form games.My cpu is Intel Core i3 370M.
I want to reduce the delay because 0.5s is too long.But now I have no idea.

### Edit 2:  new version of the program

[notebook download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvsytovt5fmxnen/%28new%292048%20game%EF%BC%882D%20and%203D%29.nb)

### Edit 3:  the advises from the original author of “2048 Wolfram Style”

I asked the original author to help me how to improve speed,and  he give me three advises.It is very helpful!

1. Use graphics multi-primitives whenever you can. This means instead of writing something like {Sphere[point1, r], Sphere[point2, r]}, use {Sphere[{point1, point2}, r]}. This works with many graphics objects.
2. Use floating point arithmetic. This means instead of using 1/16 or Log[2, 5], use 1/16. or Log[2., 5.].
3. You could also try to Rasterize the textures and numbers in advance.

[his advises](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/05/09/2048/)

My lastest program can [download here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xv18nodx88eod6/2048%20game%282D%20and%203D%29v2.nb)

Comment: Please also post self-contained working code here as text to make this easier to work with.

Comment: The game is a little bit slow, but quite playable on my computer. (Nice game, by the way.) My computer is fairly old (2008), but reasonably fast for its age. Perhaps you should comment on what hardware you have?

Comment: @OleksandrR.Intel Core i3 370M.When I press the arrow key ,it will be 0.5s delay before image update in 3D form, while it will be less than 0.1s delay in 2D form.

Comment: `Tube`s are rendering time hogs - you may want to get rid of them.

Comment: @YvesKlett I want to draw a cuboid with rounded corners,so I need to use Tube Or Cylinder and Sphere. These two methods will spend the same time.

Comment: Just saying - `Tube` will slow down your rendering somewhat bad. Did you benchmark the solutions from your previous question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49313/131?

Comment: @Kuba huh? Did I miss something?

Comment: @Kuba it would be interesting to see if those perform better than the more compact `Tube` ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett I've not checked it :) Usually I'm too lazy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the main bottlenecks in your code are the texture you apply on each surface. Try to use `texture = {};` in your `drawTile` function and the graphics should be faster by magnitudes.

Additionally, as Yves mentioned, `Tubes` are a performance killer too.

Therefore, a workaround for your problem might be to `Rasterize` the texture graphics by yourself and use the smallest possible resolution which is acceptable for you.

I haven't looked at your complete implementation, but I guess you redraw (and therefore recreate) each tile when you play your game and use the arrow keys. What you then should do is to pre-render all needed textures. If I'm right then you only need all 2^n numbers on the surface which means with 11 images you have all needed graphics.

Therefore, a starting point is to define something like

```
$textures[n_] := ($textures[n] = 
   Rasterize[
    Graphics[{colorForNumber[n, "Background"], 
      Polygon[{{-0.45, -0.45}, {-0.45, 0.45}, {0.45, 
         0.45}, {0.45, -0.45}}], 
      Text[Style[n, Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
        FontSize -> 
         Scaled@Switch[IntegerLength@n, 1 | 2, .5, 3, .4, _, .34], 
        colorForNumber[n, "Color"]]]}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
     PlotRange -> 0.4], RasterSize -> 40])
```

and setting `texture = $textures[n];` in your `drawTile` function. Be careful not to `` Clear["Global`*"] `` because this also removes the memoization of your textures. With this each texture is only computed once.

Comment: Thanks for your advises！I rewrite my drawTile function.Now it contains fewer primitives.Also I used some caches and reduce the quality of images( Method -> {"CylinderPoints" -> 7, "TubePoints" -> 7}).Now the delay may be less than 0.2s.

Comment: @Chenminqi you should perhaps post an answer yourself, together with the revised code. The `TubePoints` option deserves a bit attention!