# Shading colours reversed on negative bar charts

Tags: bugs, front-end, graphics3d, charts, rendering

**Bug introduced in version 11.0**

---

Using simple cuboids in `BarChart3D` results in flipped colours for negative bars.  Any ideas how to fix this simply?

```
cuboid = Graphics3D[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}],
   Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 30, ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2},
   ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}];
```

[image]

```
BarChart3D[{1, 2, -3, 4}, ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Red, Yellow},
 ChartElements -> cuboid, ViewPoint -> {-1, -2, 0.5}]
```

[image]

The reversed shadows really mess up the [`roundedCuboids`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49347/363).

```
BarChart3D[{1, 2, -3, 4}, ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Red, Yellow},
 ChartElements -> Graphics3D[{roundedCuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, 1/8]}],
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -2, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Created using *Mathematica* 11.0.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: both look fine in v10.1

Comment: @george2079 Thanks George. Also ok in v7.0.1

Comment: Reproduced with version 11.0.1 on Windows 7 x64, with version 10.4.1 on the same system it is OK. The `Graphics3D` expressions are identical in the both versions. So it is a `Graphics3D` rendering bug introduced in version 11.

Comment: Same problem with OSX, MMA v 11.0.1.

Comment: Reported as a bug.